# Sqlalchemy : Find strings that contains specific character at the end of the text

Tags: python, string, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write sqlalchemy query that finds data contains specific character at the end of the data. For example, I have data like this.

```
column

apple
anaconda
```

Among those, I want to get data 'anaconda' which contains alphabet 'a' at the end of the string. This is the sqlalchemy query I've been working on.

```
query = 
read_session.\
query(tablename.column)\
.filter(tablename.column.contains('%a').all()
```

And yet I couldn't get the result that I want. I would like to know which part went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're effectively doing `LIKE '%%a%'` instead of just `LIKE '%a'`. Read the documentation on [`contains()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.contains). You should be using [`endswith()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.endswith) instead:

```
query = read_session.query(tablename.column).\
    filter(tablename.column.endswith('a')).\
    all()
```